# Face Detection not Working on Certain Devices

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using this project in GitHub: https://github.com/gankit0701/Face-Mask-Detection-In-android-App

This one uses TensorFlow Lite for mobile (Android). It detects whether a person wears a mask or not. It draws a box (red/green) on top of the faces.

My weird problem is that, if I install the demo APK directly on the device, the face mask detection is working perfectly. But when I open the project in Android Studio and run the project from there, the detection do not work, there are no drawn boxes, the inference time is always zero. But everything works perfectly when I install it using the demo APK: https://github.com/gankit0701/Face-Mask-Detection-In-android-App/tree/master/apk

One thing more to note is that, I have two devices, one is huawei phone, the app works on this device via apk or via Android Studio. The other one where it doesn't work via Android Studio is a RockChip Android device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TFLite calls inside are deprecated. So, reason it fails "fresh-build" is because of deprecated calls.
I have changed some to launch app on android 8.0 (Failed on newer versions) but you should check all the code:
TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java@129:

```
d.tfLite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(assetManager, modelFilename), new Interpreter.Options().setNumThreads(NUM_THREADS));
```

TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java@281:

```
  @Override
  public void setUseNNAPI(boolean isChecked) {
    if (tfLite != null && isChecked) {
      // NnApiDelegate nnApiDelegate = new NnApiDelegate(loadModelFile(assetManager, modelFilename));
      // tfliteOptions.addDelegate(nnApiDelegate);
      // tflite = new Interpreter(tfliteModel, tfliteOptions);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to use NNAPI, application should be rewritten. As an example see [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/lib_support/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/Classifier.java)

Comment: I tried commenting the lines with the deprecated calls, but the detection is still not working on the device. By the way, the Android version is 7.1.2

Comment: Have you debug app on rockchip device? Whats going around inference call? Any error/warning? Have you tried separate model with [native benchmark](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement#native_benchmark_binary) on suspicious device?

Comment: There were no error messages. Normally, on a device where the app is working fine, it shows in the logs: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 84... But on the rockchip device it is always - Processing 0 results from 84..